# Unable to find a usable idle daemon

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, daemon

I am trying to use Talon SRX with WPILib for First Robotics for Java in Visual Studio Code. I follow the instructions here: https://phoenix-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ch05a_CppJava.html. But when I get to the step where I try the build test - https://phoenix-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ch05a_CppJava.html#frc-java-build-test-single-talon - I get the following message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to find a usable idle daemon. I have connected to 100 different daemons but I could not use any of them to run the build. BuildActionParameters were DefaultBuildActionParameters{, currentDir=c:\Users\furch\OneDrive\Documents\TalonLibrairy\Test\TestTesr, systemProperties size=59, envVariables size=59, logLevel=LIFECYCLE, useDaemon=true, continuous=false, injectedPluginClasspath=[]}.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Please Help if You can.

Answer (score 9):

This problem is happening for using third party packages in which they allocated too much system memory with that your machine is not compatible. May be that's the reason behind it.

so how to resolve this issue :

1. go to `gradle.properties` file and you will find something like `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M`
2. now change it to  `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024M`,replace `1024` in place of `1536` after that re-run your emulator. Hopefully this issue will be resolved.

Comment: _JAVA_OPTIONS : -Xmx512M in your environment variables, close cmd and run again, I tried it then it work successfully

Answer (score 3):

if your error is like this :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to find a usable idle daemon. I have connected to 100 different daemons but I could not use any of them to run the build.
```

you know there is two way for fix this that I try and get fixed :

1. you can try create :

   ```
   _JAVA_OPTIONS : -Xmx512M in your enviroment variables
   ```

2. start Task Manager with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>delete</kbd>
   and find java and choose the java and click on <kbd>end proccess</kbd> next try again to build your app.I use the secound way with end proceess and it was successfull.I think your heap is full and need to stop or increase.I hope it usefull =))

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but it was solved once I restarted my IDE, I was using IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 10.

Comment: I got that error with ubuntu 19, intellij 2019.1 and gradle 5.2.1. Pretty sure intellij was using the port that gradle wanted, which is why shutting intellij down fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I turned off my device
The app was working fine and then I found that error

[image]

And I solved it this way in `gradle.properties`
change `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024M`  instead of `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is solved for me by updating the gradle files

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tried many solutions but it did not worked.
I install a Vpn that it caused this problem, uninstall it and sloved problem.