# Android Studio Error Code: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] , Error: Gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

The app was working perfectly and after adding a java class and a layout it crashed, removing the code didn't work and grade won't compile.

my build.grade:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.realproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

my build log output:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.NoUsableDaemonFoundException: Unable to find a usable idle daemon. I have connected to 100 different daemons but I could not use any of them to run the build. BuildActionParameters were DefaultBuildActionParameters{, currentDir=/Users/danrotman/AndroidStudioProjects/RealProject, systemProperties size=118, envVariables size=12, logLevel=LIFECYCLE, useDaemon=true, continuous=false, injectedPluginClasspath=[]}.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:157)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:98)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:218)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runPhasedAction(ProviderConnection.java:179)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:245)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.lambda$run$0(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:62)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonInitialConnectException: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:176)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:147)
    ... 23 more
2021-07-28 08:00:32,748 [ 607886]   INFO - adleSyncState$SyncStateUpdater - onFailure(RESOLVE_PROJECT:8, com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.) 
2021-07-28 08:00:32,748 [ 607886]   INFO - cState$SyncStateUpdaterService - stopTrackingTask(RESOLVE_PROJECT:8) 
2021-07-28 08:00:32,749 [ 607887]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection. (1 s 197 ms) 
2021-07-28 08:00:32,749 [ 607887]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(GradleExecutionErrorHandler.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.doGetUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:181)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.checkErrorsWithoutQuickFixes(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:59)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.getUserFriendlyError(GradleProjectResolver.java:798)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:720)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$0(GradleExecutionHelper.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.java:246)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:142)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:523)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.lambda$execute$1(ExternalSystemUtil.java:372)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceHeavyActivities.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceHeavyActivities.java:20)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:372)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:631)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:935)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:442)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$null$3(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:629)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonInitialConnectException: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:176)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:147)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:98)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:218)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runPhasedAction(ProviderConnection.java:179)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:245)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.lambda$run$0(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    ... 1 more

2021-07-28 08:00:32,807 [ 607945]   WARN - ues.SyncIssueUsageReporterImpl - Multiple sync failures reported. Discarding: SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_TOO_LOW 
2021-07-28 08:00:32,819 [ 607957]   INFO - ativeWorkspaceModificationTask - NDK support for project 'RealProject' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
2021-07-28 08:00:32,820 [ 607958]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home 
2021-07-28 08:00:32,825 [ 607963]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [/Users/danrotman/AndroidStudioProjects/RealProject] resolution task executed in 1314 ms. 
2021-07-28 08:00:33,429 [ 608567]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 11 ms 
2021-07-28 08:02:09,500 [ 704638]   WARN - actions.CopyTBXReferenceAction - Cannot find TBX tool for IDE: AndroidStudio 
2021-07-28 08:02:09,666 [ 704804]   WARN - actions.CopyTBXReferenceAction - Cannot find TBX tool for IDE: AndroidStudio 
2021-07-28 08:02:35,426 [ 730564]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 4.2.2 
2021-07-28 08:02:35,436 [ 730574]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 4.2.2 
2021-07-28 08:03:32,198 [ 787336]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appCodeInsightSettings took 80 ms 
2021-07-28 08:03:53,910 [ 809048]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 50 ms, FindSettings took 16 ms 
2021-07-28 08:03:53,973 [ 809111]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=RealProject, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=/Users/danrotman/AndroidStudioProjects/RealProject)CompilerConfiguration took 11 ms
```

This is the second time this happened last time I re-installed android studio and it resolved the problem, but that not a real solution. Please help.

Comment: Hey Dan, Welcome to the community! There is something wrong with your Gradle files. Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318491/unable-to-find-a-usable-idle-daemon. And if you are working behind proxy you would like to check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953380/android-studio-gradle-build-error-the-first-result-of-the-daemon-was-empty-mos